# mgcv GAM: more than one variable in `by` argument (smooth varying by more than 1 factor)

Tags: r, smoothing, gam, mgcv, brms

I need to model a smooth term over more than one factor. The `by` argument allows me to model one smooth per factor level, but I cannot find how to do that over multiple factors.

I tried solutions akin to the following, but with no success:

```r
data <- iris
data$factor2 <- rep(c("A", "B"), 75)

mgcv::gam(Sepal.Length ~ s(Petal.Length, by = c(Species, factor2)), data = data)
#> Error in model.frame.default(formula = Sepal.Length ~ 1 + Petal.Length + : variable lengths differ (found for 'c(Species, factor2)')
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Any help is welcomed!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the issue created by `interaction()` is that it changes the model's matrix, meaning that some variables contained in the model's data are changed:

```r
m <- mgcv::gam(body_mass_g ~ s(flipper_length_mm, by = interaction(species, sex)), data = palmerpenguins::penguins)
head(insight::get_data(m))
#>   body_mass_g flipper_length_mm       species    sex
#> 1        3750               181   Adelie.male   male
#> 2        3800               186 Adelie.female female
#> 3        3250               195 Adelie.female female
#> 5        3450               193 Adelie.female female
#> 6        3650               190   Adelie.male   male
#> 7        3625               181 Adelie.female female
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

This can lead to some issues when using postprocessing functions, for instance for visualisation.

However, following Gavin's and IRTFM's answers, this can be easily addressed by adding the variables as fixed effects in the model.

Here is a demonstration, also illustrating the differences between two separate smooths and the interaction:

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.0.5

set.seed(1)

# Create data
data <- data.frame(x = rep(seq(-10, 10, length.out = 500), 2),
                   fac1 = as.factor(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), length.out = 1000)),
                   fac2 = as.factor(rep(c("X", "Y"), each = 500)))
data$y <- data$x^2 + rnorm(nrow(data), sd = 5)
data$y[data$fac1 == "A"] <- sign(data$x[data$fac1 == "A"]) * data$y[data$fac1 == "A"] + 50
data$y[data$fac1 == "B"] <- datawizard::change_scale(data$y[data$fac1 == "B"]^3, c(-50, 100))
data$y[data$fac2 == "X" & data$fac1 == "C"] <- data$y[data$fac2 == "X" & data$fac1 == "C"] - 100
data$y[data$fac2 == "X" & data$fac1 == "B"] <- datawizard::change_scale(data$y[data$fac2 == "X" & data$fac1 == "B"] ^ 2, c(-50, 100))
data$y[data$fac2 == "X" & data$fac1 == "A"] <- datawizard::change_scale(data$y[data$fac2 == "X" & data$fac1 == "A"] * -3, c(0, 100))

# Real trends
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, color = fac1, shape = fac2)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

```r
# Two smooths
m <- mgcv::gam(y ~ fac1 * fac2 + s(x, by = fac1) + s(x, by = fac2), data = data)
plot(modelbased::estimate_relation(m, length = 100, preserve_range = F))
```

[image]

```r
# Interaction
m <- mgcv::gam(y ~ fac1 * fac2 + s(x, by = interaction(fac1, fac2)), data = data)
plot(modelbased::estimate_relation(m, length = 100, preserve_range = F))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The last model manages to recover the trends for each of the factors' combination.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an interaction variable that has 6 levels with, what else, the `interaction` function:

```
data$Sp.by.fac2 <- with(data, interaction(Species,factor2,
                                   drop=TRUE)) # 'drop' addresses Gavin's concern
library(mgcv)
gam(Sepal.Length ~ s(Petal.Length, by = Sp.by.fac2), data = data)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
Sepal.Length ~ s(Petal.Length, by = Sp.by.fac2)

Estimated degrees of freedom:
1.42 3.04 1.00 1.82 2.28 1.00  total = 11.55 

GCV score: 0.1209707
```

I have also had success using the `rms+Hmisc` package combo in constructing meaningful two-D spline surfaces. Those plot very nicely with lattice plots.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "meaningful two-D spline surfaces". mgcv has multidimensional smoothers.

Comment: You’ll want to watch the levels on the creates factor; by default there will be all combinations of the levels of the two factors even if those combinations don’t exist in the data. Not sure what role 2d surfaces play here; there’s only one continuous variable.

Comment: @GavinSimpson  If you had two independent spline bases, then wouldn’t their geometric product be a 2d surface even if they were calculated with the same RV?  If not, then the question itself is flawed because you would get multi-collinearity.

Comment: @Roland: yes , mgcv does have 2d smoothers. But this was asking for the construct of the smoothing bases from a single RV, but with stratification on two categorical covariates.

Comment: @IRTFM how can you have independent basis when they're both generated from the same continuous variable?

Comment: I share your statistical qualms  The breakpoints for the two spline bases are different so they may be sufficiently different that the mathematical machinery doesn't break. It seems very unlikely that a test of statistical significance would support using both smooths.

Answer (score 0):

> You can make an interaction variable

The problem with creating an interaction variable manually is that it complicated the process of postprocessing (interpretation and plotting).

I tried specifying two separate smooth terms in the formula, which returns different smooth for the different combinations of levels. But it seems (unsurprisingly) that it does not take into account the interaction, i.e., it computes the "main effect" of the `by=Species` and that of `by=factor2`.

```r
set.seed(1)

data <- iris
data$factor2 <- as.factor(sample(c("A", "A", "B"), 150, replace = T))
data$Petal.Length <- sqrt(data$Petal.Length)

m <- mgcv::gam(Sepal.Length ~ s(Petal.Length, by = Species) + s(Petal.Length, by = factor2), data = data)

plot(modelbased::estimate_relation(m, length = 100, preserve_range = FALSE))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

I did try using a tensor products, but it doesn't seem suited for factors:

```r
m <- mgcv::gam(Sepal.Length ~ t2(Petal.Length, factor2, by = Species), data = data)
#> Error in smooth.construct.cr.smooth.spec(object$margin[[i]], dat, knt): factor2 has insufficient unique values to support 5 knots: reduce k.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Why does it complicate the post processing an understanding? All it is doing is making a separate spline for level group that you want; you don't need to use this as the factor variable that accounts for the group means. By that I mean you could do: `y ~ f1 * f2 + s(x1 by = f12)` where `f1` and `f2` are the two separate factors and `f12` is the one created by `interaction()`.